# MVC 5 show errormessage input field while typing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

This is a piece of my current model:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "First name is required!")]
public string FirstName { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Email name is required!")]
[EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid email address!")]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

Is it possible to show the ErrorMessage while typing and not when the "out of focus" of the input occurs? The view is auto-generated.

**UPDATE**
This piece of code was provided by @vendettamit. It is working 50%. The problem is that I have more ErrorMeesages and they all pop out.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var settngs = $('form').data('validator').settings;
    settngs.onkeyup = function () {
        $('form').valid();
    };
    settngs.onfocusout = false;
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the validator object of unobtrusive jquery validation. Change the event that should trigger the validation.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var $validatr = $('form').data('validator');
        var settngs = $validatr.settings;

        settngs.onkeyup = function (element, eventType) {
            if (!$validatr.element(element))
            {
                $(this.currentForm).triggerHandler("invalid-form", [this]);
            }
        };

        settngs.onfocusout = false;
    });
```

**Update** -

1. It seems you have to manually trigger the validation for onkeyup. Updated the snippet.
2. Updated with trigger for single element validation.

Check out all validation options for more customization [here](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#options).

Comment: I get this error: validator.settings[eventType].call is not a function. How can I get the "real" name of validator?

Comment: Check the updated version of snippet. I didn't test the previous snippet. But now it should work fine.

Comment: Thx for helping me, but now I get this error $(...)[0].valid is not a function.

Comment: Yes it is working, but I have more "ErrorMessages" and they all pop out and not just the one from the input I am inserting.

Comment: Well I would never come to this solution. Thank you!

Comment: I am using the same piece of script for another form, but I get this error: TypeError: $validatr is undefined, var settngs = $validatr.settings;

Comment: try `$('form')` in console and see if it has a validator data attribute. If not then you can also get the validator object by `var $validatr = $('form').Validate()`.

Comment: I tried var $validatr = $('form').Validate() and I got the same error. If I try $('form') in the console I get this: <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="/Manage/ChangePassword" novalidate="novalidate">.

Comment: Make sure you have validator added in the page. It it's added and still doesn't appear.. Ask a separate question question with more details.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery Validate 1.17 and Unobtrusive, elements are already validated at every keystroke, but message is not shown if there's no message placeholder for each element. You may add it using the [`ValidationMessageFor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.htmlhelpervalidationextensions.validationmessagefor?view=aspnetcore-2.1) method :

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
<div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

Note that key validation is not used until field is "submitted" - after a tab switch for example.